# Actionbarsherlock : How to "keep" it in 1 class

Tags: actionbarsherlock

I'm completely new to Java and Android..
While using actionbarsherlock, I'm having a problem that I can't solve.
My app has around 8 Activities in total, and each of them has the SAME action bar,
using ABS.

So I was wondering if there is a way to keep the whole ABS part in 1 class,
and then call it in other activities when needed. Or else, I would have to write the same code in each activity to reach the same action bar, which really doesn't look correct.

I remember before using ABS, I had to use a separate row in XML then inflate it in other activities when needed. But this whole ABS project seems too vast for a newbie like me and I'm
really getting confused.. can any one help me clarify? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a base class which sets up the action bar.

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
  @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.whatever....
  }
}
```

And then in your activities...

```
public class MySweetActivity extends BaseActivity {
  @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.whatever);
  }
}
```